# How to disown a subprocess in Python

Tags: python, subprocess

I have a Python program that starts a subprocess via `Popen`. Since the subprocess is a child of Python process, it will be killed if the Python process is killed.

How can I start a process in Python so that it would be a child of init (PID 1) instead of Python?